# Intercepting all action sent to the NgRx Store

Tags: action, ngrx, store

I'm new with NgRx.
I made some code, but the result is not exactly what intended.
I would like to intercept every action sent with the  `dispatch()` function to the store.

My goals are the following:

1. intercept every action sent to the store in a custom Effect, and print the text (Intercepting action...) to the console without modifying the action. (The Effect, that handles this action, should work normally.)
2. if the action (that was previously sent to the store) made its job (i.e. the corresponding Reducer made modifications on the store), I also want to "react" on this, and print another message (Got state from store.) on the console

I have 2 problems in my code:

1. the texts appear in  the wrong order (i.e. first "Got state from store", then "Intercepting action...", then "Got state from store" again).
2. to intercept every action, I make an array of all of the actions, defined in the application, and call `ofType()` with this array. If a new action is implemented, I have to manually update this array. Is there a way to retrieve the registered actions directly from the store ?

Below is the code:

**app.module.ts**

```
//to register the Effect to intercept the actions
imports: [
EffectsModule.forRoot([InterceptorEffects]),
]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
//here I react to the changes of the store
_interceptorSubscription: Subscription;
this._interceptorSubscription = _store.pipe(select((state, props) => console.log("Got state from store.")) );
```

**interceptor.effect.ts**

```
//the Effect that should intercept every action
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class InterceptorEffects {
    private readonly _interceptAllAction$ = createEffect(() =>
        this._actions.pipe(
            ofType(...[JobActions.downloadResultAction, JobActions.deleteJobAction]),
            tap(() => console.log("Intercepting action..."))
        )
        , { dispatch: false } );

    constructor(private _actions: Actions) {}
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask why you need this?
To answer the question:

1. AFAIK you can't do this. An action first reaches all reducers, and then it's handled by effects. If you want to register actions BEFORE they reach a reducer, take a look at meta reducers.
2. To react to all actions in an effect, don't use the `ofType` operator, and simply subscribe to the Actions stream.

Comment: Thanx for the hint. I try to control a custom loading-bar; i.e. (Start-of-action)->(Show-bar)  resp.  (End-of-action)->(Hide-bar). Not all action do http-req. Should i check the state of the store to accomplish this ? Do you allow me 2 other questions ?: 1) "...actions first reaches reducers...": does this mean the on() of the corresp. reducer is triggered AND every matching "select(...)" statement is calculated ? 2) in the statement  "createEffect(() => this._actions.pipe(ofType(SomeAction), share()), { dispatch: false });"  : what is the purpose of specifying both "share()" and "dispatch" ?

Comment: 1) yes  2) you dont need share, dispatch so the action isn't send to the store

Comment: Thanx for your answer.